# Tumblr API with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, tumblr

I'm brand new to ruby and am currently building a rails application that needs to pull from a Tumblr blog. I have read through several questions here, online tutorials and Tumblr's API docs and after two weeks, I'm stuck.

https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

I make the call using Tumblr in my controller

```
require 'json'
require 'tumblr_client'
client = Tumblr::Client.new :consumer_key => 'consumerkey'
@post = client.posts 'crossfitinterchange.tumblr.com', :type => 'text', :limit => 1, :filter => 'html'
```

Then this is returned (short snippet)

```
{"blog"=>{"title"=>"Today's Workout", "name"=>"crossfitinterchange", "posts"=>118, "url"=>"http://crossfitinterchange.tumblr.com/", "updated"=>1444971275, "description"=>"", "is_nsfw"=>false, "ask"=>false, "ask_page_title"=>"Ask me anything", "ask_anon"=>false, "share_likes"=>true, "likes"=>0}, "posts"=>[{"blog_name"=>"crossfitinterchange", "id"=>131266609424, "post_url"=>"http://crossfitinterchange.tumblr.com/post/131266609424/friday-oct-16th-wod", "slug"=>"friday-oct-16th-wod", "type"=>"text", "date"=>"2015-10-16 04:54:35 GMT", "timestamp"=>1444971275, "state"=>"published", "format"=>"html", "reblog_key"=>"OWmgAbMO", "tags"=>[], "short_url"=>"http://tmblr.co/ZE0_uk1wG6O4G", "recommended_source"=>nil, "recommended_color"=>nil, "highlighted"=>[], "note_count"=>0, "title"=>"Friday Oct 16th WOD", "body"=>"<p>[STRENGTH]</p>\n\n<p>5 x 3 Push Press to find 3RM</p>\n\n<p>* complete 5 ring rows after each set</p>\n\n<p><br/>\n[CONDITIONING]</p>\n\n<p>7 mins EMOM:</p>\n\n<p>5 sit ups<br/>\nME Thrusters (115/80#) for duration of round</p>\n\n<p><br/>\n- REST 2 mins -</p>\n\n<p><br/>\n2 mins AMRAP Box Jump Overs (24/20&quot;)</p>\n\n<p><br/>\nScore is total Thrusters + Box Jump Overs</p>", ...
```

In my view I have

```
<% @post.each do |p| %>
<%= p.title %>
<%= p.body %>
<% end %>
```

I get an error that title and body are undefined.
I'm getting the JSON returned via the API, now how do I grab the title and body of the post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `@post` object contains JSON data. So, you don't need to loop through that i.e. no need to use `.each` on that object.

To grab the `title` and the `body` from the `@post` JSON object, you should do:

```
title = @post['blog']['title']
body = @post['blog']['body']
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I put in the above and I was given a TypeError `no implicit conversion of String into Integer`. Do I need to parse the JSON before?

Comment: I thought `@post` is already a JSON? If not, then yes, make it a json object using `.to_json` call and then try my suggestion above. It should work. Let me know if not!

Comment: It should be according to the API documents. Some other questions I've read though say it's JSONP or some form of JSONP.

Comment: You can check the object type in your program: `puts @post.class` If not, make it json by: `@post = @post.to_json`. Then: `@post['blog']['title']` etc.

Comment: When I do `puts @post.class` in irb the response is `Hash` `=> nil`.

Comment: if its a hash, then you should be able to make it a json by: `@post.to_json` and if the json looks like the one you posted in your question, then my answer will work.